# How to slide text and images from left to right with sliding effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I am creating a web page where I need to slide the text and image in such a way that image slides from left and then the text slides from right on clicking a button by using jquery/javascript.

Please check this [slider](http://www.intellicompute.com/) I want my texts and image to  slide like this

Please suggest me with necessary js/JQuery

Comment: pls check the link I have provided

Comment: Did you search for it? Found anything? Tried anything?

Comment: On that page used http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: Ya, have you search for it? Or are you waiting for others to search for you?

Comment: I have gone through web found many. But none of them was not this kind

Comment: @Thejdeep, http://www.intellicompute.com/wp-content/themes/doover/js/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.js?ver=2.1.1

Comment: `none of them was not this kind`. So you *did* found something of this kind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example on [Jquery API](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8HrpE/)

Tutorial on [daneden.me](http://daneden.me/animate/)

```
he text and image in such a way that image slides from left and then the text slides from right on clicking a button by using jquery/javascript
```

This you put inside the div and this is a solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
position: relative;
background-color: #abc;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
float: left;
margin: 5px;
}
</style>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p><button id="go">Run »</button></p>
<div class="block"></div> <div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div> <div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div> <div class="block"></div>
<script>
$( "#go" ).click(function(){
$( ".block:first" ).animate({
left: 100
}, {
duration: 1000,
step: function( now, fx ){
$( ".block:gt(0)" ).css( "left", now );
}
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My answer is a helpful for you? @Thejdepp

Comment: Thanks @Mirko Cianfarani I will check this and let you know

Comment: I will be waiting for the news from you @Thejdeep

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with css3 & jquery.

There are some nice Plugins & tutorials. Download them and tweak it as u wish.

http://www.sequencejs.com/themes/category/free/

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/15/parallax-content-slider-with-css3-and-jquery/

Comment: I wouldn't yet recommend CSS3, it is not working in some older versions of IE such as the 8.