# Slide functionality

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am looking help for jquery half slide function from left to right, please go through below url and get more information.
http://jsfiddle.net/prabunivas/Fy9Hs/2/

```
<div>
    <div id="col1" style="float:left">
        <div style="display:none">Slide DIV</div>
    </div>
    <div id="col2">
        <div style="width:320px;border:1px solid red">Actual content
           <input type="button" id="slide-btn" value="slide" />
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _please go through below url and get more information_. Please provide more information _here_ where it is useful.

Comment: What do you want to achieve ?please provide jQuery you tried

Comment: Duplicate. See this close answered question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855397/how-to-slide-text-and-images-from-left-to-right-with-sliding-effect

Answer (score 0):

Below is the updated code from your fiddle

HTML

```
<div>
    <div id="col1" style="float:left; display:none">
        <div>Slide DIV</div>
    </div>
    <div id="col2">
        <div style="width:320px;border:1px solid red">Actual content<input type="button" id="slide-btn" value="slide"/></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Some CSS

```
  #col1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #ccc;
  }
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slide-btn').click(function(){
      $('#col1').toggle("slide");
    });
});
```

Youl will have to add jQuery UI 1.10, more information about slide is available at 
http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/, more information about toggle is available at http://jqueryui.com/toggle/